# Исключение повторение переменных PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Когда я беру рандомные значения из БД, они часто повторяются. Чтобы это не происходило, я попытался заново брать значение, но это не помогает.

```
<?php

        $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root','','engtest');
        $result = array( $result_transfer1,$result_transfer2, $result_transfer3, $result_transfer4);
        $result_word;
        $transfer = array( $transfer1 , $transfer2,$transfer3, $transfer4);

        $result[0] = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND()");
        $transfer[0] = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[0]));

      switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {

        case 'button1':
            if($transfer[0] == $transfer[1] or $transfer[0] == $transfer[3] or $transfer[0] == $transfer[2]){
                unset( $result[0]);
                $result[0] = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND()");
                $transfer[0] = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[0]));
                echo "($('.answer1').html('" . $transfer[0]['transfer'] ."');";}
            else{ echo "$('.answer1').html('" . $transfer[0]['transfer'] ."');";};
        break;}
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вам нужно чтобьы в текущей выборке из нескольких значений не повторялись элементы или чтобы значения были разными при разных запросах к скрипту.

Comment: Если значения не будут повторятся никогда - то они уже не рандомные. Если вам нужны уникальные значения то при запросе используйте список тех значений, которые вы уже видели и они уже не интересны, в виде `select id from words where id not in(1,2,3) order by rand()`. Еще не понятно, зачем заново выполнять запрос внутри блока case, можно же просто второй раз  сделать fetch из переменной запроса выполненного в начале скрипта и он вернет следующую строку той же выборки, которая заведомо не равна предыдущей

Comment: '$result[0] = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from words  order by rand()");
$transfer[0] = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[0]));

$result[1] = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM words WHERE id NOT IN(' . $transfer[0]['id'] . ') ORDER BY RAND()');
$transfer[1] = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[1]));'     Написал так, но все равно бывает повторяется

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поиграться с `GROUP BY`

```
 $result[0] = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `words` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Первым делом убедитесь, что в вашей таблице не повторяются сами записи, если надо чтобы уникальным было какое-то конкретное поле, попробуйте `GROUP BY field_that_must_be_once` и желательно я думаю ограничить выбор через `LIMIT` или какие-то критерии `HAVING`, а то вы похоже всю таблицу достаёте.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать запрос с параметром DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `words` ORDER BY RAND()
```

Можно так же сгруппировать по конкретному столбцу:

```
SELECT `word` FROM `words` GROUP BY `word` ORDER BY RAND()
```